# How do first text come behind to last text in scrolling text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, forms

I want adding a area of scrolling text. Actually i used the **marquee tag** and it is worked but first text is not coming behind to last text and marquee tag no longer supported.

[image]

```
  <div class="container">
      <ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">START TEXT</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
          <li class="list-group-item">FİNİSH TEXT</li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

How do first text come behind to last text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the ul will more than fill the container vertically then one simple method is to have a complete copy of the list items and transform the ul element half way (in terms of its height) up in the Y direction.

Here's a simple example. Using transform has the advantage that the GPU will be invoked, but you still need to be aware that it's taking processing power (about 12% GPU on my laptop) so I suppose might eventually be a battery flattener if run for extended periods.

```css
.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.list-group {
  animation: goup infinite 2s linear;
}

@keyframes goup {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">START TEXT</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">FİNİSH TEXT</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">START TEXT</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">FİNİSH TEXT</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: İT İS MAGİC :) !! Thank you sir it's working.